# How to make json_decode faster

Tags: php, json, caching

I've got ~100k rows in MySQL in one table and every row contains a column with output from `json_encode`. I need to load all rows and decode this data.

This takes a few seconds and I want to try and make it faster. I was thinking about `Memcache`, so I wrote a little benchmark and it is not faster than `json_decode`.

I have a full access to the machine where it runs (so the solution does not to be on PHP script side only) and it is pretty strong with 8 CPUs and 4G of RAM. Most of the time the machine is doing nothing.

Any ideas how to make it faster?

Comment: Memcached has to encode the data that it stores, and I think it uses JSON format. So using memcached is just doing the same work you're trying to avoid.

Comment: Actually, I think it uses `serialize()` format. It's a little more efficient, but there's still plenty of overhead in decoding it.

Comment: I was using `serialize()` before `json_encode()` and it was even slower. So memcache is a no-go..

Comment: Yeah, I just read in another question that `json_decode` is faster since PHP 5.3.

Comment: You could normalize the data so that it's *not JSON* and then you can skip encoding too.

Comment: you can try using mysql's json datatype https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract